# How to let print() pass arguments to a user defined print method in R?

Tags: r

I have defined an S3 class in R that needs its own print method. When I create a list of these objects and print it, R uses my print method for each element of the list, as it should.

I would like to have some control over how much the print method actually shows. Therefore, the print method for my class takes a few additional arguments. However, I have not found a way to make use of these arguments, when printing a list of objects.

To make this more clear, I give an example. The following code defines two objects of class `test`, a list that contains both objects and a print method for the class:

```
obj1 <- list(a = 3, b = 2)
class(obj1) <- "test"
obj2 <- list(a = 1, b = 5)
class(obj2) <- "test"
obj_list <- list(obj1, obj2)

print.test <- function(x, show_b = FALSE, ...) {
  cat("a is", x$a, "\n")
  if (show_b) cat("b is", x$b, "\n")
}
```

Printing a single object works as expected:

```
print(obj1)
## a is 3 
print(obj2, show_b = TRUE)
## a is 1 
## b is 5
```

When I print `obj_list`, my print method is used  to print each object in the list:

```
print(obj_list)
## [[1]]
## a is 3 
## 
## [[2]]
## a is 1
```

But I would like to be able to tell `print()` to show `b` also in this situation. The following (a bit naive...) code does not produce the desired result:

```
print(obj_list, show_b = TRUE)
## [[1]]
## a is 3 
## 
## [[2]]
## a is 1
```

Is it possible to print `obj_list` and at the same time pass the argument `show_b = TRUE` to `print.test()`? How?

Comment: It looks like `print.default` ignores `...`.     "`...: further arguments to be passed to or from other methods. They are ignored in this function." Printing a `list` ends up in `print.default`. So you'd have to find some way to bypass it.

Comment: I *think* the problem is that `obj_list` is not of class `test`, it is just a `list`. You could try `class(obj_list) <- c("test", "list")` and in `print.test` check if the object inherits from `list` and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Josh. Following your advice I defined my own print method for lists. This works (and thus  I posted it as an answer), but I'm a bit uncomfortable with the solution. It means, of course, that any list will be printed using my methods, instead of  `print.default()` from base R. And I tend to trust functions from base R more than my own functions...

Comment: @user2706569: You are right that letting the list have class `test` could be used to solve the problem. But this is not what I want to do. The class defines the single objects and not the list of these objects. And since one can construct lists from anything in R, it would still be possible to put `obj_list` in a list and print this list. With the old problem reappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Josh's suggestion, I found a way to avoid `print.default()` being called when printing a list. I simply wrote a print method for lists, since none seems to exist as part of base R:

```
print.list <- function(x, ...) {
  
  list_names <- names(x)
  if (is.null(list_names)) list_names <- rep("", length(x))
  
  print_listelement <- function(i) {
    if (list_names[i]=="") {
      cat("[[",i,"]]\n", sep="")
    } else {
      cat("$", list_names[i], "\n", sep="")
    }
    print(x[[i]], ...)
    cat("\n")
  }
  
  invisible(lapply(seq_along(x), print_listelement))
  
}
```

The relevant part is that `...` is passed on to `print`, when the objects inside the list are printed. So now, coming back to the example in the question, printing a list of `test` objects works together with `show_b =TRUE`:

```
print(obj_list, show_b = TRUE)
## [[1]]
## a is 3 
## b is 2 
## 
## [[2]]
## a is 1 
## b is 5
```

However, I am a bit uncomfortable with defining `print.list` myself. Chances are that it is not working as well as the built-in printing mechanism for lists.

Comment: If you're only ever going to printing list containing entirely `test` objects, you could make your `print.list` function only test if all the elements of the list are `test`; if they are use your method; if not just call `print.default(x, ...)` to fall back to default methods.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This would be safer because I wouldn't mess with printing other lists than those exclusively built from `test` objects. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it...